# Filling NAs for a value in a column, leaving out a single row unchanged

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I used `fill()` to replace NAs in my variable called 'values', works all good, but now I want it to leave one row unchanged. I don't want to use `group_by()`, just `!`. I'm not sure how to insert it within the fill function.

Here is a sample dataframe I created:

```
y <- data.frame(values=c(2,2,NA,5,NA,NA,3,3),
                groups=c("A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","B1","B1")
)
```

This is the output of the df:

```
  values groups
1      2     A1
2      2     A1
3     NA     A1
4      5     A2
5     NA     A2
6     NA     A3
7      3     B1
8      3     B1
```

Then I run the fill function:

```
y %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  fill(values, .direction = 'down')
```

Here's the output, but I want the line 6 to stay NA, using `!` only.

```
  values groups
1      2     A1
2      2     A1
3      2     A1
4      5     A2
5      5     A2
**6      5     A3**
7      3     B1
8      3     B1
```

Comment: Your code as is achieves that. https://i.imgur.com/ObRZEGt.png

Comment: How do you determine that _that_ row should remain unchanged? Is it because group `A3` only has 1 row? Frankly, without knowing your data, the presence of a column names `groups` suggests to me that you may not _want_ to fill across groups.

Comment: Agreed with Phil. When I run your code on your sample data, I get your desired result. Can you doublecheck that the problem is really there?